# How to solve "ORA-00904: : invalid identifier" while creating table?

Tags: sql, oracle

When I try to create a table it fails with `ORA-00904: : invalid identifier`. Here is my table.

```
create table eas_citizen_text_info (
    UID bigint(12) Primary key,
    Gender char(15),
    First_name varchar(30),
    Middle_name varchar(30),
    Last_name varchar(30),
    DOB date Not null,
    Age int(3),
    Caste varchar(30),
    Martial_status varchar(15),
    Address varchar(255),
    House_No_Bldg_Apt varchar(75),
    Street_Road_Lane varchar(75),
    Landmark varchar(75),
    Area_locality_sector varchar(75),
    Village_Town_City varchar(75),
    Post_office varchar(75),
    District varchar(25),
    Sub_district varchar(25),
    Pincode int(15),
    State varchar(30),
    Father_name varchar(200),
    Mother_name varchar(200),
    Guardian_name varchar(200)
);
```

Comment: `bigint(12)` is not Oracle syntax.  Just use `number`.

Comment: i want it to be unique and 12 digits in length, wch datatype will be perfect for my requirement?

Comment: I would use `char(12)`, unless you want it to be system generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Oracle's datatypes. Define number columns with `0` precision to make them integers. Use `varchar2` rather than `varchar` (although Oracle will change it for you).

```
create table eas_citizen_text_info (
    UID number(12,0) not null Primary key,
    Gender varchar2(15),
    First_name varchar2(30),
    Middle_name varchar2(30),
    Last_name varchar2(30),
    DOB date Not null,
    Age number(3,0),
    Caste varchar2(30),
    Martial_status varchar2(15),
    Address varchar2(255),
    House_No_Bldg_Apt varchar2(75),
    Street_Road_Lane varchar2(75),
    Landmark varchar2(75),
    Area_locality_sector varchar2(75),
    Village_Town_City varchar2(75),
    Post_office varchar2(75),
    District varchar2(25),
    Sub_district varchar2(25),
    Pincode number(15,0),
    State varchar2(30),
    Father_name varchar2(200),
    Mother_name varchar2(200),
    Guardian_name varchar2(200)
);
```

However we still get the error:

```
  UID number(12,0) not null Primary key,
    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier


SQL>
```

But Oracle has been generous enough to point out which column is the cause of the error. If we check the documentation we find `UID` in the list of SQL reserved keywords. [Find that here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621).

The solution is simple: change  `UID` to something safe such as  `CITIZEN_UID` and the table can be created:

```
SQL> create table eas_citizen_text_info (
  2      citizen_UID number(12,0) not null Primary key,
  3      Gender varchar2(15),
  4      First_name varchar2(30),
  5      Middle_name varchar2(30),
  6      Last_name varchar2(30),
  7      DOB date Not null,
  8      Age number(3,0),
  9      Caste varchar2(30),
 10      Martial_status varchar2(15),
 11      Address varchar2(255),
 12      House_No_Bldg_Apt varchar2(75),
 13      Street_Road_Lane varchar2(75),
 14      Landmark varchar2(75),
 15      Area_locality_sector varchar2(75),
 16      Village_Town_City varchar2(75),
 17      Post_office varchar2(75),
 18      District varchar2(25),
 19      Sub_district varchar2(25),
 20      Pincode number(15,0),
 21      State varchar2(30),
 22      Father_name varchar2(200),
 23      Mother_name varchar2(200),
 24      Guardian_name varchar2(200)
 25  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: @ShailendraTorane -  " now m gettng this error *Missing right parenthesis*". You are not running the exact same code. The error means you  have a syntax error in your statement, specifically, um, a missing right bracket. That means you have a `(` which is not balanced by a `)`. You need to look at your code with a cool eye: attention to detail is a key skill for successful programming.

Answer (score 0):

Database languages such as Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL do not support integer length bigger than 12 digits and also big integers. So you have change your query like this:

```
create table eas_citizen_text_info (
    UID int(12) Primary key,
    Gender char(15),
    First_name varchar(30),
    Middle_name varchar(30),
    Last_name varchar(30),
    DOB date Not null,
    Age int(3),
    Caste varchar(30),
    Martial_status varchar(15),
    Address varchar(255),
    House_No_Bldg_Apt varchar(75),
    Street_Road_Lane varchar(75),
    Landmark varchar(75),
    Area_locality_sector varchar(75),
    Village_Town_City varchar(75),
    Post_office varchar(75),
    District varchar(25),
    Sub_district varchar(25),
    Pincode int(12),
    State varchar(30),
    Father_name varchar(200),
    Mother_name varchar(200),
    Guardian_name varchar(200)
);
```

Comment: m getting the same error"904" again.. :( m using oracle 10g db express edition!!

Comment: check your 7 th line DOB date

Comment: table header can not have  space between them.so change it to DOB_date/something like this

Comment: i want to include "YYYY-MM_DD" in the date column, wch datatype shud i use ?? date?

Comment: just use date datatype

Comment: i tried the above query after changing the reserved keyword UID to Citizen_UID.. bt now m gettng this error "Missing right parenthesis"

Comment: use varchar in this line:

    Gender varchar(15),

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your first column declaration 'UID bigint(12) Primary key' .Use 'number' instead of 'bigint' as **UID number(12) Primary Key** 
See this image for reference[It will surely help you.[][1]][1]